# What purpose of turn on warnings then turn off?

Tags: perl, warnings

Reading souce code of `File::Find::Closure` module from [here](https://github.com/briandfoy/file-find-closures/blob/master/lib/File/Find/Closures.pm), I can't understand the purpose of these line:

```
package File::Find::Closures;
use strict;

use warnings;
no warnings;
```

- Why the author turn off warnings immediately after turn on?
- Is there something in `warnings` module that can not turn off after turning on?

Comment: Probably a policy required 'use warnings' but did not disallow 'no warnings'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Functionally speaking, it makes no sense. It's the same thing as simply using

```
no warnings;
```

I can think of three motivations:

1. The coder is subject to a policy that requires the use of `use warnings;`, and he wanted to violate the spirit of the policy while still following the letter of the policy.
2. The coder wanted to override `-w` by using `no warnings;`, and he erroneously thought he had to load the module using `use warnings;` first.
3. The coder wants to use `use warnings;`, so he did, but the module isn't ready for it, so he added `no warnings;` temporarily.

Answer (score 1):

You would normally use `no warnings` in a block of code, and `use warnings` for the whole block.

Consider the following:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $one = "one" + 2;

{
no warnings;
my $two = "two" + 2;
}

my $three = "three" + 2;
```

---

This will trip warnings for vars `$one` and `$three`, but not `$two`:

```
Argument "one" isn't numeric in addition (+) at stack.pl line 5.
Argument "three" isn't numeric in addition (+) at stack.pl line 12.
```

The use you describe above makes the `use warnings` pragma redundant, as all the `no warnings` will apply to the rest of the block.

Comment: I know this case, but the author turn off **immediatly** after turn on, that the thing make me trouble.